# Qual a diferença entre sendRedirect e requestDispatcher.forward?

Tags: java, java-ee, aplicação-web, servlet

Qual a diferença fundamental entre o uso dos métodos

```
response.sendRedirect("Alguma pagina");
```

e

```
RequestDispatcher despachar = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Alguma pagina");
despachar.forward(request, response);
```

já que "fazem o praticamente o mesmo"?
Até onde  eu sei o sendRedirect() cancela a requisição atual e inicia uma nova requisição.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A diferença está entre ***redirecionar** o cliente para uma página* (*sendRedirect*) e ***encaminhar** uma requisição para ser atendida por outro recurso* (*forward*).

No primeiro caso (*sendRedirect*), o cliente receberá uma resposta http em cujo *header* haverá a informação de que ele deve requisitar outra página, e o browser fará esta requisição. Ou seja, o redirecionamento ocorre no lado no cliente.

No segundo caso (*forward*), no lado do server a requisição do usuário será encaminhada para ser atendida por outro recurso (outro *servlet*). Este outro *servlet* eventualmente devolverá outra página para o usuário.

A diferença é bem grande principalmente no que tange à experiência do usuário.

Infelizmente há muitos sistemas que usam encaminhamento de requisição quando deveriam usar redirecionamento.

## Exemplos de mal uso do *forward*

O usuário clica para salvar uma edição (faz um submit da página). Então o servidor salva os dados no banco de dados e **encaminha** (*forward*) o usuário para a página que exibe para leitura o registro recém editado.

No browser, o usuário fez um submit e como resposta recebeu o conteúdo de outra página. O navegador renderiza o conteúdo recebido mas não registra que está em outra página e não atualiza por exemplo a URL.

Um dos problemas disso é que o usuário não poderá salvar nos seus favoritos a página da exibição do registro para leitura. Para o navegador é como se o usuário ainda estivesse na página de edição. Isso limita também o uso dos botões de "voltar" e "avançar" do navegador, que vão passar a não oferecer o comportamento que o usuário está acostumado.

## Experiência Web

A experiência proposta pela Web e que geralmente é esperada pelos usuários, é que qualquer sistema Web seja composto de **navegação** entre páginas. Cada recurso é uma página diferente, com sua própria URL, e você pode voltar para um recurso anterior e avançar novamente para o recurso onde estava antes, pode salvar recursos nos favoritos para voltar a eles depois facilmente, pode compartilhar estes recursos compartilhando URLs, etc.

Mesmo os sistemas web que oferecem a experiência **single page application**, se bem projetados, proporcionam ao usuário esta experiência de navegação entre páginas. Por exemplo: **gmail**, **google maps**, **facebook**...

Nestes sistemas, raramente ou talvez nunca a página é inteiramente recarregada, mas apenas parte do conteúdo dela é redesenhado. Isso melhora a experiência do usuário mas há uma preocupação enorme para que ele não perca aquela outra experiência básica de ter a URL atualizada e de poder depois acessar recursos específicos pelo botão de voltar ou por uma URL salva nos favoritos ou que foi compartilhada com ele por outro usuário.

Usar encaminhamento (**forward**) em vez de usar redirecionamento (**sendRedirect**) mata esta experiência e não motiva o desenvolvedor a se aprimorar no desenvolvimento web pois ele se acostuma a aproveitar recursos no servidor entre uma página e outra, quando ele deveria se utilizar principalmente das informações contidas nas requisições do usuário e guardar muito pouco ou nenhum estado no servidor.

Comment: seria de grande ajuda conhecer mais  alguns problemas do uso de encaminhamento em vez de redirecionamento.

Comment: @Muito interessante, obrigado!! Vou ficar atento para o lance do bookmark!

Comment: @Caffé, muitíssimo obrigado pela resposta esclarecedora, estava justamente com este problema da não atualização da URL ao retornar do servlet e consegui resolver seguindo sua dica. Simplesmente trocando:

    request.getRequestDispatcher().forward("arquivo.jsp");
    request.setAttribute("objObjeto", objeto);

Por:

    resp.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/recurso/" + object.getId());