# Sem resultado ao enviar dados de uma form em JSP

Tags: java, html, java-ee, jsp

Estou tentando fazer uma mini-tela de login, pegar os dados da form comparar e após isso redirecionar para uma pagina *JSP*.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Login
<form>
<input type="text" name="login">
<input type="password" name="password">
</form>
<form>
<input type="submit" name="submit">

<!-- Declaração de variaveis -->
<%!String logdefault = "admin";
String passdefault = "admin"; %>
<% String login = request.getParameter("login");
String password = request.getParameter("password"); %>
<!-- FIM declaração de variaveis -->

<%
if(login.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")){
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
System.out.println("deu certo");
}else{
System.out.println("algo deu errado");
}
%>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Tentei antes usar o `if` comparando com `==` porém ao clicar em `submit` não acontecia nada, ao tentar com `equals` me devolve esse erro

> An exception occurred processing JSP page /Login.jsp at line 31

Comment: RonnySilva, acredito que a resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256640/6789) possa ajudar na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente você deve direcionar no action do form o nome da sua servlet para assim enviar os dados dos inputs, pegando esses dados com o `request.getParameter("")` para assim fazer a validação e passando a mensagem de erro ou não para um `request.setAttribute("");`. e redirecionado para pagina desejada de acordo com o `RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("");
rd.forward(request, response);'
 E não o`response.sendRedirect("");`

Olha nesse link a difeença entre um e outro

[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90410/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-sendredirect-e-requestdispatcher-forward](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90410/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-sendredirect-e-requestdispatcher-forward)
    `

Ficaria assim o mais ou menos

```
<form action="servlet_qualquer" method="post">
<input type="text" name="login">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
```

Sua servlet qualquer

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   // processRequest(request, response);
   String certo="deu certo";
    String erro="deu errado";


    String login = request.getParameter("login");
      String senha = request.getParameter("password");

   if(login.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")){

    request.setAttribute("certo", certo); 
   RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/certo.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);


    }else{
   request.setAttribute("erro", erro); 
   RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/pagina_erro.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

}

}
```

Pagina certo.jsp

```
    <c:if test="${!empty certo}">
                    <p  style="color:red;" align="center">${param.certo}</p><br/>
                </c:if>
```

Pagina errado.jsp

```
<c:if test="${!empty erro}">
                    <p  style="color:red;" align="center">${param.erro}</p><br/>
                </c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo enunciado da sua pergunta o seu propósito é implementar segurança. Então, tenha em mente que no Java EE, os containeres são responsáveis por fornecer segurança de aplicativos.

Um container basicamente provê dois tipos de segurança: declarativa e programática. E é uma boa prática, sempre que possível, evitar de reinventar a roda correndo o risco de deixar de aproveitar os recursos que linguagem proporciona.

E considere o seguinte:

> O formulário de login deve conter campos para inserir um nome de usuário e senha. Esses campos devem ser nomeados j_username e j_password, respectivamente. O formulário de autenticação deve postar esses valores no nome lógico j_security_check.
>
> Todos esses nomes que começam com j_ são padronizados pela especificação Java Servlet - precisamos apenas seguir a convenção para permitir que os mecanismos automáticos funcionem.[[Michal Cmil et al -  2014](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/java-ee-7-development-wildfly), 310 p.]

Acredito que no seu caso, altere o seu formulário conforme a seguir:

```
<form method="post" action="j_security_check" >
  <input type="text" name="j_username" >
  <input type="password" name="j_password">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">

    <!-- Declaração de variaveis -->
    <%!String logdefault = "admin";
    String passdefault = "admin"; %>
    <% 
    String login = null; 
    String password = null;  

    /**
     * Procure evitar misturar lógica na camada de apresentação.
     * Isso fere o designer Pattern MVC - Lógica fica no Controller.
     */
    if(request.getParameter("login") != null
      && request.getParameter("password") != null){
        login = request.getParameter("login");
        password = request.getParameter("password"); 

      if(login.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")){
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        System.out.println("deu certo");
      }else{
        System.out.println("algo deu errado");
      } 
    }
    %>

</form>
```

<sub>**Observação**: Eu entendi que se trata de código de experimentação, no entando, é de senso comum evitarmos implementar lógica na camada de apresentação. Isso fere o designer pattern MVC.</sub>

Caso seja necessário implementar alguma lógica na camada de apresentação, o correto seria usar a Expression Language - EL.

> A ligação entre uma página JSF e um bean de suporte Java é feita através de EL. Você pode usar instruções EL para imprimir o valor das variáveis, acessar os atributos dos objetos em uma página ou invocar um método de bean de suporte.[[Gonçalves, Antonio - 2013](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DREFM0O), 321 p.]
>
> A sintaxe básica para uma instrução EL é #{expr}

As declarações #{expr} serão analisadas e avaliadas pelo tempo de execução JSF. As expressões EL podem usar a maioria dos operadores Java usuais.

- Aritmética: +, -, *, / (div),% (mod),
- Relacional: == (eq),! = (ne), <(lt),> (gt), <= (le),> = (ge),
- Lógico: && (e), || (ou),! (não), e
- Outro: (), vazio, [] ,.

Espero ter ajudado.

<sub>**Nota**: mais detalhes sobre segurança: [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256625/6789).</sub>

---

**Referência**: 
<sub>[Juneau, Josh -  2013], Apress, © 2013, **[Java EE 7 Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430244259)**: A problem-Solution Approach – Proven Solutions for Java Enterprise Edition 7 Developement</sub> 
<sub>[Gonçalves, Antonio -  2013], Apress, © 2013, **[Beginning Java EE 7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DREFM0O)** (Expert Voice in Java)</sub>
<sub>[JSR 196 - JASPIC], **[JSR 196 - JASPIC](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=196)**: JavaTM Authentication Service Provider Interface for Containers</sub>
<sub>[Anjana Mankale -  2013], Copyright © 2013 Packt Publishing, **[Spring Security 3.x Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/spring-security-3x-cookbook)**: Over 60 recipes to help you successfully safeguard your web applications with Spring Security.</sub>
<sub>[Michal Cmil et al -  2014], Copyright © 2014 Packt Publishing, **[Java EE 7 Development with WildFly](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/java-ee-7-development-wildfly)**: Leverage the power of the WildFly application server from JBoss to develop modern Java EE 7 applications.</sub>