# O que ocorre internamente quando usamos request.getRequestDispatcher?

Tags: java, aplicação-web

Quando utilizamos o `request.getRequestDispatcher()` ele faz o **encaminhamento** da requisição para outra servlet para ser atendida (correto?). A questão que eu queria saber é: internamente, ele faz essa invocação (não sei se esse é o termo correto) da outra servlet por uma nova requisição HTTP ou é algo parecido a chamada de um método?

Comment: Aqui está uma boa explicação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90410/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-sendredirect-e-requestdispatcher-forward

Answer (score 0):

Todo o processo ocorre internamente sem envolver o cliente ou navegador. Visualmente a gente não vê o endereço encaminhado, mas ocorre uma requisição interna.

Comment: Mas como ocorre essa requisição entre as Servlet dentro do servidor? Ela chama um método? Ou é HTTP?

Comment: Sim, ele repassa a requisição (http) para o outro recurso, que pode ser uma servlet, jsp ou algum outro arquivo.

Comment: Aqui está uma boa explicação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90410/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-sendredirect-e-requestdispatcher-forward